# How to download streamlit output data frame as excel file

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, button, streamlit

I want to know if there is any way to download the output dataframe of streamlit as an Excel file using the streamlit button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example so that it's easier for people to understand your question and to help you.

Here is the answer if I understand you correctly. Basically it provides 2 ways to download your data `df` as either csv or xlsx.
**IMPORTANT**: You need to install `xlsxwriter` package to make this work.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import io

# buffer to use for excel writer
buffer = io.BytesIO()

data = {
    "calories": [420, 380, 390],
    "duration": [50, 40, 45],
    "random1": [5, 12, 1],
    "random2": [230, 23, 1]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

@st.cache
def convert_to_csv(df):
    # IMPORTANT: Cache the conversion to prevent computation on every rerun
    return df.to_csv(index=False).encode('utf-8')

csv = convert_to_csv(df)

# display the dataframe on streamlit app
st.write(df)

# download button 1 to download dataframe as csv
download1 = st.download_button(
    label="Download data as CSV",
    data=csv,
    file_name='large_df.csv',
    mime='text/csv'
)

# download button 2 to download dataframe as xlsx
with pd.ExcelWriter(buffer, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    # Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

    download2 = st.download_button(
        label="Download data as Excel",
        data=buffer,
        file_name='large_df.xlsx',
        mime='application/vnd.ms-excel'
    )
```

Comment: This mostly worked for me, but the Excel file is blank (0 bytes) after downloading it. To get it to work, I called `writer.save()` in between `df.to_excel()` and the download button. Worked like a charm afterward. Appreciate, the help, Subaru.

Comment: I will need to check that, and this answer will need to be updated because st.cache is deprecated I believe